# Calculate number of pending tasks at given time points (ideally with dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a database containing a list of events. Each event has an associated start date, and a date when the event ended or was completed, eg:

```
dataset <- tibble(
  eventid = sample(1:100, 25, replace=TRUE), 
  start_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2012/01/01'), by="day"), 25),
  completed_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2012/01/01'), as.Date('2014/01/01'), by="day"), 25)
)

    > dataset
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   eventid start_date completed_date
     <int> <date>     <date>        
 1      57 2011-01-14 2013-01-07    
 2      97 2011-01-21 2011-03-03    
 3      58 2011-01-26 2011-02-05    
 4      25 2011-03-22 2013-07-20    
 5       8 2011-04-20 2012-07-16    
 6      81 2011-04-26 2013-03-04    
 7      42 2011-05-02 2012-01-16    
 8      77 2011-05-03 2012-08-14    
 9      78 2011-05-21 2013-09-26    
10      49 2011-05-22 2013-01-04    
# ... with 15 more rows
>
```

I am trying to produce a rolling "snapshot" of how many tasks were pending a different points in time, e.g. month by month. Expected result:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 2
   month      count
   <date>     <int>
 1 2011-01-01    0
 2 2011-02-01    3 
 3 2011-03-01    2
 4 2011-04-01    2
 5 2011-05-01    4
 6 2011-06-01    8
```

I have attempted to group my variables using `group_by(period=floor_date(start_date,"month"))`, but I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction!

I would prefer a solution using dplyr if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand rows for each month included in the range of dates with `map2` from `purrr`. `map2` will iterate over multiple inputs simultaneously. In this case, it will iterate through the start and end dates at the same time.

In each iteration, if will create a monthly sequence using `seq` (or `seq.Date`) from start to end month (determined from `floor_date`). The result is nested for each row of data (since one row can have multiple months in the sequence). So, `unnest` is needed afterwards.

The `transmute` will add a new variable called `month_year` (and drop the old ones) and use `substr` to extract the year and month only (no day). This is the first through seventh character of the date.

Then, you can `group_by` the month-year and `count` up the number of pending projects for each `month_year`.

I included `set.seed` to reproduce from data below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

dataset %>%
  mutate(month = map2(floor_date(start_date, "month"),
                      floor_date(completed_date, "month"), 
                      seq.Date, 
                      by = "month")) %>%
  unnest(month) %>%
  transmute(month_year = substr(month, 1, 7)) %>%
  group_by(month_year) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

**Output**

```
   month_year count
   <chr>      <int>
 1 2011-01        1
 2 2011-02        3
 3 2011-03        9
 4 2011-04       10
 5 2011-05       13
 6 2011-06       15
 7 2011-07       16
 8 2011-08       18
 9 2011-09       19
10 2011-10       20
# … with 22 more rows
```

If you want to exclude the completed month (except when start month and completed month are the same, if that can exist), you can subtract 1 month from the sequence of months created. In this case, you can use `pmax` so that if both start and end months are the same, it will still count the month).

Here is the modified `mutate` with `map2`:

```
mutate(month = map2(floor_date(start_date, "month"),
                    pmax(floor_date(completed_date, "month") - 1, floor_date(start_date, "month")), 
                    seq.Date, 
                    by = "month"))
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)

dataset <- tibble(
  eventid = sample(1:100, 25, replace=TRUE), 
  start_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2012/01/01'), by="day"), 25),
  completed_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2012/01/01'), as.Date('2014/01/01'), by="day"), 25)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is super helpful! It took me a while to go through your code and understand what it does but I think I now get it. There are however some unexpected results - for example, let's say an event has start_date = 2015-04-15 and completed_date = 2015-06-15.  seq.Date here would generate 3 entries (2015-04-01, 2015-05-01 and 2015-06-01), so that when the dataset is grouped by month_year, this event would be counted as "pending" in April, May and June 2015, while I would expect it not to be counted for June. I tried removing the last element of the output of map2 to no avail!

Comment: @greymatter999 See edited answer. If you don't want to count the `completed_date` month, you can subtract 1 from the `floor_date` month result in `map2`. In this case, you can also include `pmax` so if start and end months are the same, it will still count the month. Let me know if this addresses the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code was already very clear - I just wasn't familiar with map2 and I had to read about it! Everything is super clear. Thank you so much :)